# Adding Sidebars in WordPress Theme

Tags: themes, sidebar

Can anyone help me on how to add two sidebars on the main page of my WordPress site.
I need one on the left and the right.
I'm new to WordPress and don't know much about the code, even when I tried reading the codex.
My website is [here](http://www.sushidelivery.com.ph)
I am using a Ready To be theme, with Ready E-Commerce plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your funtions.php to register sidebar

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Sidebar ',
        'id'=>'sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<p>',
        'after_title' => '</p>',
));
```

To use it in your theme use the following

```
<?php 
    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar') ) :
    endif;
?>
```

Refer this to know more : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: Okay, so I will just put both of these into functions.php right?

Comment: No...use the first one in functions.php. Use the second one in your template page to call the sidebar instead of `get_sidebar()`

Comment: Can you mark it as the "answer" if you have got what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

use register_sidebar function.[register sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).

for using on your themes;

```
<?php if ( is_dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-name') ) {
        dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-name');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, where will I put this code block?

Comment: look [here](http://i.imgur.com/RTnWRcs.png) or look there https://github.com/murtaugh/HTML5-Reset-WordPress-Theme/blob/master/sidebar.php